# How to store current scroll position while rotating app?

Tags: android, scroll, rotation, savestate, appcompatactivity

I'm making a manga application but I stuck with save current scroll position when user rotate their device (landscape to portrait or portrait to landscape). I'm using RecyclerView and GridLayoutManager. Here is two block code that I have researched on the internet:

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rvItems.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt("position"));
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("position", ((GridLayoutManager)rvItems.getLayoutManager()).findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition());
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

I'm using it and either in `onResume()` or `onPause()`, none of them are working. So I'm asking for any idea or suggestion that solve my problem? Any comment will be approriate.

P/S: One more problems, Is there any solution for stop loading all resource/data in current activity while user rotates their screen? I mean in my application, there might be numerous data and resource either text and images, as I know,  every time user rotate their screen, the function `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` was called which every data in `onCreate()` function will be loaded again. I need the resource/data only load one time since it's opened, then it won't load resource when user rotates their screen.

My writing might be very bad but now I'm sticking with many problems without any solution I can think or search in internet.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

add this to your activity tag in manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Comment: why? he doesn't want to load all the data again when the screen rotates

Comment: Because there are other configuration changes and other reasons why the Activity could be destroyed and recreated. There are proper ways to load data (namely the [`Loader` framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)) that behave appropriately with regard to the activity lifecycle and configuration changes. It is better to encourage these best practices instead of things like this.

Comment: @masoudvali Thanks for your reply but it doesn't work for me. The scroll position still not stored. I have tried many ways but none of them working. It's just like loading the layout again. Any other ideas or just a key works of my problem and I'll search them myself.

Comment: try `android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation"`, it works for me

Comment: @masoudvali Thanks. But I was using it with `onConfigurationChanged()`,  It just loads the layout again, not store the position. Or am I using it the wrong way?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use both at the same time but i don't know for sure